# Grammar of motto "Sancte et Sapiente"

Tags: grammar-identification

The motto of King's College is "Sancte et Sapiente", which is translated "With Holiness and Wisdom". Am I correct in understanding that two of the three words are adverbs, so a literal translation would be "holy-ly and wisely"? Could someone legitimately claim that "sapiente" is in the ablative ("with wisdom")?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The actual motto of the coat of arms, as indicated on [their website](https://www.kcl.ac.uk/akc) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coat_of_arms_of_King%27s_College_London), is "sancte et sapiente**r**" (with an "r" at the end).

These are the standard adverbial forms of *sanctus* ("holy," from [*sancio*](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/sancio)) and *sapiens* ("wise", from [*sapio*](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/sapio)). Both adverbial forms are listed at the bottom of the linked Lewis & Short entries.

Literally, it means:

> In a holy way ("holily"?) and wisely

More idiomatically:

> With holiness and wisdom

Searching for *sancte et sapiente* (without the *r*) shows scattered results from poor quality sites about the motto of King's College London as well as a [university in Liberia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuttington_University). These are mistakes, though: *sapiente* could be ablative, but it would be the ablative of the adjective *sapiens*, meaning "[with a] wise one." You would need to put *sapientiā* for something that could plausibly be translated, "with wisdom."